# For a 3x3 matrix with complex eigenvalues, does Matlab [evecs, evals] = eig(A) always return the real eigenvalue in the first column?

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra, complex-numbers, eigenvalue

I will only be dealing with 3x3 matrices of real numbers `A`. I need to find the eigenvalues using Matlab. I know I can use the function `eig(A)` to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors. The matrices that I will be finding the eigenvalues for will produce real and/or complex eigenvalues.

Question:
When the matrix produces imaginary eigenvalues and I use the `[evecs, evals] = eig(A)` function in Matlab, **will the real eigenvalue always be in the first column?** (Remember `A` is a 3x3 matrix)

The reason I'm asking this is because in every example I find, it always shows the real eigenvalue in the first column. BUT, it is not explicitly stated that for a 3x3 matrix `eig()` will return the real eigenvalue first.

It has been working so far under this assumption but **I will be processing tons of data** and if this is not the case then it could render the data useless. Also, I could just add a few lines to determine which eigenvalue is the real one but that would take computational time which in my case would add additional minutes per execution.

If the case is that it returns the real eigenvalue first (for a 3x3 matrix) then that would save a lot of time.

Comment: `eig` doesn’t promise any type of order in its output. The current algorithm for 3x3 real matrices might always put real eigenvalues first, and if so you could depend on it as long as you don’t update your MATLAB installation. But I wouldn’t depend on it for generic software where you don’t control who and where it will run.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. In that case I will have to add a few lines to my code. Thank you very much.